# Display full test case in Azure test results

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have several JUnit test cases which I run on Azure:

```
@Tag("https://sometest.com")
@DisplayName("66734 Web Test - Serial Inquiry - negative")
@Test(testName = "66734 Web Test - Serial Inquiry", groups = { "multiple_runs" })
@Timeout(value = 60, unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
public void negativeSerialInquiryTest()
{
.......
}
```

When I run the tests in Azure I get:

[image]

As you can see for Test Case title I get the name of the Java Method. I would like to display this name `"66734 Web Test - Serial Inquiry"` for Test Case title. Do you know how I can configure this?

Answer (score 0):

To change the display name to  `"66734 Web Test - Serial Inquiry"` for Test Case title you have to follow  [Rename your test plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/reference-qa?view=azure-devops#q-can-i-rename-or-permanently-delete-test-cases)  and  [Publishing test results in JUnit](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/8982) .